# FastCGI and Query Strings (working in C)

Tags: c, cgi, query-string, fastcgi, lighttpd

Just a quick question about using FastCGI. I've been programming for about a month so far and I'm finding it very difficult to wrap my head around FastCGI.

Basically here are my questions.

1. How exactly can I set my Query String?
2. Is it even something I can "set" from a programming standpoint?
3. If it is something I have to set, where would I do it?

Code:

```
 while(FCGI_Accept() >= 0) {

    if (getenv("QUERY_STRING") != NULL)
    {
        strcpy(query_string, getenv("QUERY_STRING"));

        if (query_count == 0)
        {
            printf("Content-type: text/html\r\n\r\n");
            printf("Query string has no data pairs!\n");
            continue;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Content-type: text/html\r\n\r\n");
        printf("Query string does not exist!\n");
        continue;
    }
}
```

The following code always returns `NULL` for `getenv(QUERY_STRING)`.

Comment: Normally, the query string is set by the web server. For example, if you open a browser, point it at your web server and enter a URL that looks like this...(oops), http://my.server.com/?name=fred&gender=male  then the query string will be the stuff after the question mark.

Comment: @BradS. Thank you very much, this gives me some insight of where to start. This is probably a dumb question, but how exactly do I point it a my web server? I have written a function to parse my query_string into a list of name-value pairs, but that's kind of useless if I keep a NULL string haha.

Comment: I really need more context. I don't know if you are running cgi with a web server or if you're experimenting with the library using a simple demo program. I 'm also wondering if you know how to set environment variables on your host OS...so, let's start with a simple hello world program...and replace the line, printf("Hello, world!\n"); with, printf("%s\n", getenv("QUERY_STRING"));   Do you know how to run the program on the command line and set the environment variable so that the program prints out something different without compiling?

Comment: @BradS. Okay, so I made the Hello World program, but I'm encountering the same problem. So how do you set the environment variables from command line? That seems to be the part I'm stuck at. 
But yes, I'm using a web server- I wish I was knowledgeable about this to provide with more info, but all my work so far has pretty much a compilation of tutorials and asking questions.

Comment: on Windows, you can set an environment variable by saying,  set QUERY_STRING=Fred and on Linux, (assuming you're using bash) you can say, QUERY_STRING=Wilma

Comment: @BradS. So they're set the same way in Windows and Linux? Interesting, thanks for that! 
Is there a way to set them and have them be used in subsequently called programs?

Comment: No not the same in Windows and bash/Linux. On windows you have to say "set NAME=Value" (without the quotes). On Linux, you just say, "NAME=VALUE". The whole point of environment variables is that you're setting a variable in the environment that persists as long as that environment persists. So, if you open a console window and set an environment variable, it stays set as long as that window is open. Try it with the modified hello world program you made above.

Comment: BradS. Thank you for all your help, I managed to get that section of my code to work. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the form variables are passed from browser to http server in query string(for GET http request not for POST)
A html page will typically have html form with various form variables
eg

```
<HTML>

 <BODY>
  <FORM METHOD=GET ACTION="http://localhost:8888/login.cgi">
  <input name="ID" type="text">
    <input name=submit type="submit" value="Submit">

  </FORM>
 </BODY>
</HTML>
```

The user will fillup form and submit typically by clicking on submit button(which is just another form variable), browser sends GET request to webserver identified by URL as http://localhost:8888/login.cgi?ID=aa&submit=Submit where localhost:8888 identifies the ip and port where webserver is running, /login.cgi tells web server which cgi is going to serve the given http request,query string is the text that follows ? ie ID=aa&submit=Submit.

Webserver or (library provided by webserver bind into CGI) parses http request data including query string,http request headers and passes them as environment variables to cgi program. Query string is passed in env variable QUERY_STRING. The CGI programs are supposed to use these values in its application logic

Answer (score -1):

FastCGI is not working based on environment variables, that is why you will not get anything from the webserver by using getenv.

Instead, FastCGI is using a socket interface between the webserver and the FastCGI process (that is running permanently in a daemon style), i.e. your FastCGI daemon listens on a TCP socket or a Unix socket for incoming requests.

I recommend looking at this webpage which contains an explanation as well as some sample code in various programming languages - including C - for a FastCGI daemon: 
https://www.hiawatha-webserver.org/howto/cgi_and_fastcgi